# Creating and destroying threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

```
gcc (GCC) 4.6.3
c89
```

Hello,

I am just wondering if this is the best way to handle worker/background threads created by main?

I am doing this right? this is the first time I have done any multiple threading programs. Just want to make sure I am on the right track, as this will have to be extended to add more threads.

I have one thread for sending a message and another for receiving the message.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

```
int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread_send;
    pthread_t thread_recv;

    int status = TRUE;

    /* Start thread that will send a message */
    if(pthread_create(&thread_send, NULL, thread_send_fd, NULL) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create thread, reason [ %s ]",
                strerror(errno));
        status = FALSE;
    }

    if(status != FALSE) {
        /* Thread send started ok - join with the main thread when its work is done */
        pthread_join(thread_send, NULL);

        /* Start thread to receive messages */
        if(pthread_create(&thread_recv, NULL, thread_receive_fd, NULL) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create thread for receiving, reason [ %s ]",
                    strerror(errno));
            status = FALSE;

            /* Cancel the thread send if it is still running as the thread receive failed to start */
            if(pthread_cancel(thread_send) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to cancel thread for sending, reason [ %s ]",
                        strerror(errno));
            }
        }
    }

    if(status != FALSE) {
        /* Thread receive started ok - join with the main thread when its work is done */
        pthread_join(thread_recv, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example of a worker/background thread to send a message, example only

```
void *thread_send_fd()
{
    /* Send the messages when done exit */

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time when this kind of construct might be justified is if there is only ever one message exchanged and, even then, there may be some problems.

If messages are to be exchanged continually during the app run, it's more usual to write both threads as loops and never terminate them.  This means no continual create/terminate/destroy overhead and no deadlock-generator, (AKA join).  It does have a downside - it means that you have to get involved with signals, queues and the like for inter-thread comms, but this is going to happen anyway if you write many multithreaded apps.

Either way, it's usual to start the rx thread first.  If you start the tx thread first, there is a possibility that rx data will be retuned and discarded before the rx thread starts.

Answer (score 1):

Is this done once per message?  It seems like the call creates a thread to send 1 message and another thread to wait for 1 response.  Then the call, and I'm assuming the entire program, just waits for the whole thing to finish.  Assuming the receiver cannot do anything until the sender finishes sending, this does absolutely nothing to improve the real or perceived performance of your program.  Now to be precise, we would need to know what the sender and the receiver are really doing before we can tell for sure if there is any benefit from this.  For any benefit at all, the sender thread and the receiver thread would have to have work that they can do **simultaneously**....not serially.  If the intent is to not make the program wait for the send and the receive transaction, then this does not do that at all.